# How to do a clean install on a Windows computer encrypted by Bitlocker?

Tags: windows-11, bitlocker

My laptop needed a replacement motherboard. I forgot to suspend Bitlocker before the technician came and replaced the motherboard.

I understand that the data is lost and that's fine; what's important to me is that the laptop should boot as if it were a clean install of Windows 11.

I have Windows 11 as a bootable USB, but when I try to do a clean install of it I get the error that I cannot install it onto the laptop's hard drive because it is encrypted by Bitlocker.

I don't care if I lose the encrypted data. I just want to be able to use that hard drive again. Is it possible?

Comment: You need to format the disk when installing from USB.

Comment: The suggested way is to disable BitLocker protection, perform the reinstallation process, and then enable BitLocker protection.  If you cannot disable BitLocker, then your only choice, is to delete all partitions on the drive and select the unallocated partition. BitLocker does not prevent users from deleting all partitions on the drive.  You can't "install" Windows on an available partition because the drive is encrypted.

Comment: BTW, since the hardware is part of the "signature" of your Windows account, and you'll be reformatting the HD (i.e., remove partitions and then format), you likely will need to authenticate Windows again -- use the original info if available, or get MS support help.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Windows 10+ automatically detect and active on OEM machines and in specific cases with Retail licenses. Since the machine is a laptop, it will automatically activate nearly instantaneous.

Comment: @Ramhound Not really when the motherboard is replaced and that seems to be the case here.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - The author can’t use the original license since the motherboard was replaced and likewise the reinstall process will absolutely automatically detect the new license. I absolutely know that for bona fide fact.

Comment: @Ramhound, according to Microsoft you should be able to reuse a key/license after a motherboard change. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/reactivating-windows-after-a-hardware-change-2c0e962a-f04c-145b-6ead-fb3fc72b6665

Comment: @YisroelTech - That documentation only applies if your NOT reinstalling the software the author is reinstalling the software and the installation process will pickup the new OEM license